# QSqlQuery.next() return false but has data in database. Why?

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have data in my sqlite database. Insert statement executed successfully. But when want to get data from db i found nothing and this error "QSqlError("", "", "")". I have checked my query is active and not valid. How to solve this issue ?

Here is my code:

```
void FindDialog::find()
{

    QString roll_number = ui->txt_RN->text ();

    int roll = roll_number.toInt ();

    const QString findstmnt = "SELECT Roll_Number, Name FROM student_info WHERE Roll_Number = :roll";

    scon->getQuery ()->prepare (findstmnt);

    scon->getQuery ()->bindValue ("roll", roll);

    if(scon->getQuery ()->exec ()){

        qDebug() << "Active: " << scon->getQuery ()->isActive ();

        qDebug() << "Valid: " << scon->getQuery ()->isValid ();

        if(scon->getQuery ()->isActive ()){
            if(scon->getQuery ()->next ()){
                qDebug() << "Has Data: " << scon->getQuery ()->next ();
            } else {
                qDebug() << scon->getQuery ()->lastError ();
            }
        }

    } else {
        qDebug() << scon->getQuery ()->lastError ();
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a colon, that should be `bindValue(":roll", roll)`.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand where is the problem. it look like same.

Comment: sorry. Thanks. I got this Database connected.
Has Data:  false
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
Has Data:  ""
Active:  true
Valid:  false

Comment: Sounds like a completely unrelated question...

Comment: Sorry Sir, after recompile i got no value from db.

Comment: I got the query size -1

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter is not `roll` but `:roll`.

When you bind the value to the wrong parameter name, the actual parameter has its initial value, which is `NULL`.
So the query will never find any row because no value compares equal to `NULL`.

Comment: I got this after correction. Database connected.
Has Data:  false
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
Has Data:  ""
Active:  true
Valid:  false